# keycloak does not show terms and conditions page

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak v.22.0.3

I have configured a realm where I enabled 'Terms and Conditions' and made it default (set as default=true). (Realm->Authentication->Required Actions)

I was expecting that after registration I would be shown a 'Terms and Conditions' page but none is shown.

Is there anything else that I need to check? Maybe perhaps I need to setup something in the theme?